# Is it possible to set the environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" to an uploaded JWT File in Flowground?

Tags: file-upload, environment-variables, flowground

I try to use the "google-api-nodejs-client" (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) with a JSON Web Token in a flowground connector implementation. Is there a possibility to get the environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" point to a configurable JWT file that the user can upload into a flow?

Example of client usage from the library page:

```
// This method looks for the GCLOUD_PROJECT and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
// environment variables.
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
});
```

Comment: this library may sound like your problem solver: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-credentials-helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see if I understand correctly what you want to do:

- create a flow that can be triggered from outside and accesses any Google API via google-api-nodejs-client module.
- every time you trigger the flow you will post a valid JWT for accessing any Google API
- you want to store the JWT in the local file-system; the mentioned environment variables contains the path to the persisted JWT.

Generally spoken this is a valid approach for the moment.
You can create a file in the local file-system:
`fs.writeFile(process.env.HOME + '/jwt.token', ...)`
Sebastian already explained how to define the needed environment variables.
Please keep in mind that writing and reading the JWT file *must* take place in the same step of flow execution. There is no persistence of this file after finishing execution of this step.

Why is this a valid approach for the moment only?
I assume that we will prevent writing in the local file-system in the near future. This will prevent the described solution as well.
From my point of view the better solution would be using the OAuth2 mechanism build in **flow**ground.
For more information regarding this approach

- https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#oauth2-client
- https://doc.flowground.net/getting-started/credential.html

Comment: The description is correct, i chose the following solution so far: Add the JWT as a Parameter to the connector - this is working quite well, no file in need with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variables in flowground following on the "ENV vars" page for your connector:

[image]